# docker-compose上でseleniumを動かすとエラーが発生する。

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

◆ 概要
docker-composeのseleniumを動作させるとエラーが発生するが、解決できないので解決方法を教えてほしいです。
`docker-composev3 docker-selenium`
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium

◆ ファイル構成

```
./
 - docker-compose.yml
 - Dockerfile
 - app.py
 - setup.py
 - setup.cfg
```

`setup.py`

```py
from setuptools import setup
setup()
```

`setup.cfg`

```
[metadata]
name = TEST
version = 0.1.0
author = dream 
description = Test
long_description = file: README.md

[options]
packages = find:
install_requires=
    lxml
    selenium
    beautifulsoup4
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```yml
version: "3"
services:
  chrome:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome:4.0.0-beta-3-20210426
    container_name: chrome
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    ports:
      - 4444:4444
      - 5900:5900

  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: app
    volumes:
      - ./screenshots:/image/screenshots/
    tty: true
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3

ENV TZ "Asia/Tokyo"

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

RUN python setup.py install
```

テストでYahooのページを取得しようとしてみる。
`app.py`

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

class Scraping(object):
    
    def __init__(self):
        # Login URL
        URL = "https://news.yahoo.co.jp/"
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote(
            command_executor='http://chrome:4444/wd/hub',
            desired_capabilities=options.to_capabilities(),
            options=options,
        )

        # 暗黙的な待機処理
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)

        # 要素が見つかるまでの明示的な待機処理
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30)

        self.driver.get(URL)

    def get_pages(self):
        p = self.driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//*[@id='snavi']/ul[1]/li[2]/a")
        print (p)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys = System()
    sys.get_pages()
```

◆ エラーコード

```
/app/app.py:14: DeprecationWarning: desired_capabilities has been deprecated, please pass in an Options object with options kwarg
  driver = webdriver.Remote(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/app.py", line 32, in <module>
    sys = System()
  File "/app/app.py", line 14, in __init__
    driver = webdriver.Remote(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium-4.0.0b3-py3.9.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 217, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium-4.0.0b3-py3.9.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 308, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium-4.0.0b3-py3.9.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 369, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium-4.0.0b3-py3.9.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 125, in check_response
    status = value["status"]
KeyError: 'status'
```

上記のエラーが調べても解決できません。

◆ Issueとして挙がっているっぽいので、回答を待ってみるのもありですが・・・
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/9437

尚、以下のバージョンで実行しても正常に動作しないのですが webdriverのオプションの指定方法が誤っているのでしょうか？

過去のバージョンで試すも謎のループが発生して、正常に動作しませんでした。

VNCで確認するもブラウザが起動している様子はないです。

Comment: chromeではバグが存在するようでした。
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/issues/1267

以下Qiitaの記事を参考。
https://qiita.com/ryoheiszk/items/93b2d52eec370c09a22e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下のように変更することで解決しました。

```yml
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
```

↓

```yml
   shm_size: "2gb"
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```yml
version: "3"
services:
  chrome:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome:4.0.0-beta-3-20210426
    container_name: chrome
    shm_size: "2gb"
    ports:
      - 4444:4444
      - 5900:5900

  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: app
    volumes:
      - ./screenshots:/image/screenshots/
    tty: true
```